# member object constructor and enum

Tags: c++, constructor

Why does this not compile?

File.hpp

```
class CTest
{
  public:
    enum enumTest { EN_TEST };

    //constructor:
    CTest(enumTest f_en);
};
```

AnotherFile.hpp

```
#include "File.hpp"

class CAnotherTest
{
  public:
    CTest obj_Test(CTest::EN_TEST);
};
```

Visual Studio says:   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'EN_TEST'

armcc compiler says:   error:  #757: constant "CTest::EN_TEST" is not a type name

Thanks, Mirco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because,

```
CTest obj_Test(CTest::EN_TEST);
```

is evaluated as a function named `obj_Test`. Now it should have argument as a type, however, `CTest::EN_TEST` **is a value, not a type**.

If it's intended that `obj_Test` an object then you have pass `CTest::EN_TEST` to it in the constructor:

```
class CAnotherTest
{
public:
  CAnotherTest () : obj_Test(CTest::EN_TEST) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize like that. In-class initialization can be done for only `static const` integral type.

Use initialization-list in the constructor, as:

```
class CAnotherTest
{
  public:

    CTest obj_Test; //member declaration. no initialization here

    static const int value  = 100; //OK. static const integral type!

    CAnotherTest() : obj_Test(CTest::EN_TEST) {}
                 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ its called initialization-list
};

const int CAnotherTest::value; //definition goes to .cpp file
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your syntax for `CAnotherTest` is wrong.  Perhaps you mean something like this?

```
class CAnotherTest
{
  public:
    // Constructor     vvv Initialise member variable
    CAnotherTest() : obj_Test(CTest::EN_TEST) {}

    // Member variable
    CTest obj_Test;
};
```